# Plone Translations - i18ndude Preferred Language

Tags: internationalization, plone, buildout

I am hoping this is something simple I am just overlooking. We have 3 Plone sites that are **supposed** to be exactly the same in their core setup, only differing with certain products installed and the actual content. I noticed our translations are working on one site, and not on the other two. So far I can't find any differences.

We are using i18ndude (version 3.3.3) with Plone 4.3.2. We do have custom products/types with our own domain, but it is more than just those not working, it is everything in the site.

For testing, I have tried just grabbing and printing the browser's language. I did it with both `context.REQUEST['LANGUAGE']` and `context.portal_languages.getPreferredLanguage()`. I set my browser language in each attempt to 'es', 'en', and 'pt', as those are the languages we are currently supporting. The Site Language in each site is set to English. Here are my test results:

```
Browser Language set to 'es':
Site A: returned 'es'
Site B: returned 'en'
Site C: returned 'en'

Browser Language set to 'en':
Site A: returned 'en'
Site B: returned 'en'
Site C: returned 'en'

Browser Language set to 'pt':
Site A: returned 'en'
Site B: returned 'en'
Site C: returned 'en'
```

Site A and B are both on the same server, so I don't believe its a missing server package. The buildouts are almost identical for those two, but the differences are just in a couple eggs that are seemingly unrelated to this issue.

I just don't understand why it isn't even detecting the updated browser language at all, it just defaults back to the site's preferred language it seems. Except for one scenario in one site. What is strange is, these all used to work to the best of my knowledge, and I am not sure when they stopped.

I did check `context.portal_languages.getAvailableLanguages()` just to make sure the ones I am using are in there, and they are. I also checked the ownership and permissions of the locales & i18n directories, those are all a match across sites and set accurately.

**EDIT**

This is a script I quickly wrote to see what all values Plone is getting:

```
pl = context.portal_languages
langs = [str(language) for language in pl.getAvailableLanguages().keys()]
print langs
print "Preferred: ", pl.getPreferredLanguage()

ts = context.translation_service
print "Request Language: ", context.REQUEST['LANGUAGE']
print "Accept Language: ", context.REQUEST['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']

return printed
```

This is my browser language setup when running this, listed by highest priority first:

1. pt-br
2. pt
3. es
4. en
5. en-us

And this is my result (site A, which seems to recognize Spanish, but not Portuguese):

```
['gv', 'gu', 'gd', 'ga', 'gn', 'gl', 'lg', 'lb', 'ty', 'ln', 'tw', 'tt', 'tr', 'ts', 'li', 'tn', 'to', 'tl', 'lu', 'tk', 'th', 'ti', 'tg', 'as', 'te', 'ta', 'yi', 'yo', 'de', 'ko', 'da', 'dz', 'dv', 'qu', 'kn', 'lv', 'el', 'eo', 'en', 'zh', 'ee', 'za', 'uk', 'eu', 'zu', 'es', 'ru', 'rw', 'kl', 'rm', 'rn', 'ro', 'bn', 'be', 'bg', 'ba', 'wa', 'wo', 'bm', 'jv', 'bo', 'bh', 'bi', 'br', 'bs', 'ja', 'om', 'oj', 'la', 'oc', 'kj', 'lo', 'os', 'or', 'xh', 'ch', 'co', 'ca', 'ce', 'cy', 'cs', 'cr', 'cv', 'cu', 'ps', 'pt', 'lt', 'pa', 'pi', 'ak', 'pl', 'hz', 'hy', 'an', 'hr', 'am', 'ht', 'hu', 'hi', 'ho', 'ha', 'he', 'mg', 'uz', 'ml', 'mo', 'mn', 'mi', 'mh', 'mk', 'ur', 'mt', 'ms', 'mr', 'ug', 'my', 'ki', 'aa', 'ab', 'ae', 've', 'af', 'vi', 'is', 'vk', 'iu', 'it', 'vo', 'ii', 'ay', 'ik', 'ar', 'km', 'io', 'et', 'ia', 'az', 'ie', 'id', 'ig', 'ks', 'nl', 'nn', 'no', 'na', 'nb', 'nd', 'ne', 'ng', 'ny', 'kw', 'nr', 'nv', 'kv', 'fr', 'ku', 'fy', 'fa', 'kk', 'ff', 'fi', 'fj', 'ky', 'fo', 'ka', 'kg', 'ss', 'sr', 'sq', 'sw', 'sv', 'su', 'st', 'sk', 'kr', 'si', 'sh', 'so', 'sn', 'sm', 'sl', 'sc', 'sa', 'sg', 'se', 'sd']
Preferred:  es
Request Language:  es
Accept Language:  pt-br,pt;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,en-us;q=0.2
```

And results for Site B and C:

```
['en-mp', 'gv', 'gu', 'fr-dj', 'fr-gb', 'en-na', 'en-ng', 'en-nf', 'zh-hk', 'gd', 'pt-br', 'ga', 'gn', 'gl', 'en-nu', 'en-fm', 'en-ag', 'ms-my', 'ty', 'tw', 'tt', 'tr', 'ts', 'ko-kp', 'tn', 'to', 'tl', 'tk', 'th', 'ti', 'tg', 'te', 'zh-sg', 'ta', 'fr-mq', 'de', 'da', 'ar-ae', 'es-ni', 'dz', 'en-kn', 'fr-ml', 'dv', 'en-ms', 'fr-mg', 'fr-sc', 'fr-vu', 'qu', 'ar-qa', 'es-bo', 'en-nz', 'fr-bj', 'en-ws', 'fr-bi', 'zh', 'en-lr', 'fr-ch', 'fr-bf', 'za', 'fr-be', 'en-lc', 'fr-rw', 'zu', 'ch-mp', 'ar-ly', 'en-gb', 'en-nr', 'es-pr', 'tr-bg', 'en-gh', 'en-gi', 'fr-km', 'es-py', 'en-gm', 'es-pe', 'es-pa', 'en-gu', 'en-gy', 'sw-tz', 'ms-sg', 'wa', 'pt-st', 'wo', 'pt-ao', 'jv', 'fr-cd', 'ja', 'en-vu', 'es-ar', 'fr-td', 'fr-tg', 'da-dk', 'ch', 'co', 'en-vg', 'en-bz', 'ca', 'en-us', 'ce', 'en-ai', 'en-bm', 'en-vi', 'cy', 'en-bn', 'cs', 'cr', 'fr-ci', 'cv', 'cu', 'en-bb', 'ps', 'ln-cg', 'pt', 'en-au', 'zh-tw', 'es-mx', 'de-de', 'pa', 'es-ve', 'en-as', 'en-er', 'pi', 'de-dk', 'pl', 'en-sb', 'ch-gu', 'es-hn', 'en-sc', 'fr-nc', 'it-hr', 'ar-eg', 'mg', 'pt-pt', 'ml', 'mo', 'mn', 'mi', 'mh', 'mk', 'mt', 'ms', 'mr', 'fr-fr', 'hu-si', 'my', 'sv-fi', 'fr-re', 'en-pk', 've', 'vi', 'is', 'vk', 'iu', 'it', 'vo', 'ii', 'ik', 'en-io', 'fr-cm', 'io', 'ia', 'ie', 'id', 'ig', 'es-cu', 'hu-hu', 'es-cr', 'es-cl', 'es-co', 'fr-wf', 'pt-mz', 'en-il', 'it-it', 'de-be', 'fr', 'en-ke', 'fr-ga', 'fr-pf', 'es-do', 'ar-ps', 'fy', 'fr-gn', 'fr-pm', 'en-ki', 'en-ug', 'fa', 'fr-gp', 'ff', 'fi', 'fj', 'fo', 'ar-kw', 'bn-sg', 'ss', 'sr', 'sq', 'sw', 'sv', 'su', 'st', 'sk', 'si', 'sh', 'so', 'sn', 'sm', 'sl', 'sc', 'sa', 'sg', 'se', 'sd', 'bn-in', 'fr-mc', 'sv-se', 'ar-bh', 'lg', 'lb', 'la', 'ln', 'lo', 'ss-za', 'li', 'lv', 'lt', 'lu', 'sw-ke', 'en-bw', 'yi', 'en-ph', 'en-pn', 'yo', 'en-ie', 'en-pg', 'pt-cv', 'hr-ba', 'bn-bd', 'en-pr', 'en-pw', 'ss-sz', 'ar-iq', 'de-ch', 'ar-il', 'es-sv', 'el', 'eo', 'en', 'ar-dz', 'ee', 'tn-bw', 'es-gq', 'fr-gf', 'es-gt', 'eu', 'et', 'de-lu', 'es', 'ru', 'rw', 'zh-cn', 'ar-td', 'nl-nl', 'it-sm', 'it-si', 'rm', 'rn', 'ro', 'ar-sa', 'be', 'bg', 'ur-pk', 'ba', 'fr-ca', 'bm', 'bn', 'bo', 'bh', 'bi', 'fr-cg', 'fr-cf', 'es-us', 'el-cy', 'en-vc', 'sd-pk', 'ta-sg', 'br', 'bs', 'nl-an', 'sd-in', 'cs-cz', 'om', 'oj', 'fr-lb', 'en-fk', 'en-fj', 'oc', 'ln-cd', 'fr-lu', 'ar-om', 'de-at', 'os', 'or', 'tr-cy', 'xh', 'el-gr', 'de-li', 'ar-sy', 'en-jm', 'es-ec', 'ar-so', 'it-ch', 'en-ls', 'ar-sd', 'es-es', 'en-rw', 'tn-za', 'ar-jo', 'en-ky', 'en-bs', 'hz', 'ar-ma', 'da-gl', 'hy', 'en-mt', 'en-mu', 'nl-aw', 'en-mw', 'hr', 'en-tt', 'en-zw', 'ht', 'hu', 'en-to', 'ar-mr', 'hi', 'en-tk', 'ho', 'hr-hr', 'ha', 'en-tc', 'pt-gw', 'he', 'en-dm', 'fr-it', 'uz', 'en-et', 'ur-in', 'ur', 'tr-tr', 'uk', 'ms-bn', 'ug', 'aa', 'en-so', 'en-sl', 'ab', 'ae', 'en-sh', 'af', 'en-sg', 'ak', 'am', 'ko-kr', 'an', 'as', 'ar', 'en-sz', 'nl-be', 'ay', 'az', 'ar-lb', 'nl', 'nn', 'no', 'na', 'nb', 'nd', 'ne', 'ng', 'ny', 'ta-in', 'fr-yt', 'en-za', 'nr', 'nv', 'ar-ye', 'ar-tn', 'en-cm', 'en-ck', 'sr-ba', 'en-ca', 'ka', 'kg', 'en-gd', 'es-uy', 'kk', 'kj', 'ki', 'ko', 'kn', 'km', 'kl', 'ks', 'kr', 'fr-ad', 'kw', 'kv', 'ku', 'en-zm', 'ky', 'fr-ht', 'nl-sr']
Preferred:  en
Request Language:  en
Accept Language:  pt-br,pt;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,en-us;q=0.2
```

I just noticed that the list of available languages from `portal_languages` is different between those sites. Adding to the strange, but maybe a hint to the culprit?

Sorry for the long post, just trying to give as much info as I can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicions were right about it being something simple I am overlooking. Posting my find here.

In the ZMI, go to `portal_languages` and check these settings:

- Default Language
- Allowed Languages

  - ALL supported languages should be selected.
- Negotiation Scheme

  - Make sure "Use browser language request negotiation" is checked

My issue was that only the **Default language** was selected in the **Allowed Languages** selection list. I am not sure why it go reset like this or how. When using the Language Settings Control Panel I did not see the Allowed Languages option, had to go to ZMI for it.

Apparently the changes mentioned by [hvelarde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27257177/3489599) did not update this setting either.

Answer (score 0):

Search the instance part of your buildout for the environment variable `zope_i18n_allowed_languages`; it is used to restrict the languages for which po files are loaded to speed up Zope startup time and use less memory.

In your case, you should set it as follows:

```
[instance]
...
environment-vars =
    PTS_LANGUAGES en es pt
    zope_i18n_allowed_languages en es pt
    zope_i18n_compile_mo_files true
```

For more information check Maurits van Rees' [Internationalization in Plone 3.3 and 4.0](http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2010/10/i18n-plone-4#restrict-the-loaded-languages).

Comment: I added those variables to each of my instances, ran builtout and restarted. Nothing has changed. The site is still not being translated, and my script is showing my browser language as 'en'. For more details I will edit my post with my exact script I'm running and results.

Comment: Ok, I feel like I might be misunderstanding something. If in Site Setup, the Site Language is set to English, but I provide Spanish translations to all products and in above environment-vars, if a user visits my site with Browser Language set to Spanish, they should see it in Spanish, right?

Comment: For what I remember this depends on how you customized the `portal_languages` tool, but you must go inside ZMI. There are some configuration not exposed to Plone level.